# Call exception to connect hbase cluster using spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

My cluster of hbase and yarn is like below.

**hadoop@master**

QuorumPeerMain

HMaster

NameNode

ResourceManager

SecondaryNameNode

**hadoop@slave1, hadoop@slave2, hadoop@slave3**

DataNode

QuorumPeerMain

HRegionServer

NodeManager

---

I run spark-shell on master such as 'spark-shell --master yarn --jars hbase_libs'

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
scala> val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
scala> val tableName="t1"
scala> conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE,tableName)
scala> val admin = new HbaseAdmin(conf)
scala> admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)
```

After running the last line i cannot get the valid result i think. And the error is occurred like below.

---

```
scala> admin.createTable(tableDesc)
17/03/24 00:16:41 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38341 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:16:51 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=48376 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:17:11 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=12, retries=35, started=68457 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:17:31 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=13, retries=35, started=88488 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:17:51 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=14, retries=35, started=108613 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:18:11 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=15, retries=35, started=128644 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:18:31 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=16, retries=35, started=148687 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:18:51 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=17, retries=35, started=168725 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:19:11 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=18, retries=35, started=188743 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:19:32 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=19, retries=35, started=208879 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:19:52 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=20, retries=35, started=229066 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:20:12 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=21, retries=35, started=249231 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:20:32 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=22, retries=35, started=269358 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:20:52 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=23, retries=35, started=289456 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:21:12 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=24, retries=35, started=309604 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:21:32 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=25, retries=35, started=329733 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:21:53 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=26, retries=35, started=349925 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:22:13 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=27, retries=35, started=370053 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:22:33 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=28, retries=35, started=390216 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:22:53 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=29, retries=35, started=410302 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:23:13 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=30, retries=35, started=430440 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:23:33 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=31, retries=35, started=450629 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:23:53 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=32, retries=35, started=470689 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:24:14 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=33, retries=35, started=490866 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
17/03/24 00:24:34 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception,     tries=34, retries=35, started=510950 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after     attempts=35, exceptions:
Fri Mar 24 00:16:03 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},         org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:03 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:03 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:03 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:04 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:05 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:07 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:11 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:21 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:31 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:41 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:16:51 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:17:11 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:17:31 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:17:51 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:18:11 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:18:31 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:18:51 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:19:11 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:19:32 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:19:52 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:20:12 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:20:32 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:20:52 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:21:12 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:21:32 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:21:53 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:22:13 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:22:33 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:22:53 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:23:13 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:23:33 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:23:53 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:24:14 KST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
Fri Mar 24 00:24:34 KST 2017,     RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490282163189, pause=100, retries=35},     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4297)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4289)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTableAsyncV2(HBaseAdmin.java:753)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:674)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:607)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
at <init>(<console>:57)
at .<init>(<console>:61)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:     com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1561)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1581)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1738)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:134)
... 51 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58383)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1592)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1552)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:225)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yammer.metrics.core.Gauge
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 61 more
```

I cannot access to hbase on spark-shell. What should i do? :(

Comment: try to add the `metrics-core-2.2.0.jar` with `--jars`. If you are on a Edge Node, it should be somewhere (eg: /usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/).

Comment: @L.CWI Thank you ! It works i want. But i look over the list of classes in metrics-core-2.2.0.jar file. I do not understand what class is helpful to resolve my problem.